# How to cast String to the generic information that it represents?

Tags: java, casting

My goal is to cast to a generic type, the information that a String contains, being this information variable between the different Java types. Ex:

```
String s = "10";
E e1 = (E)s;
```

```
String s = "abc";
E e2 = (E)s;
```

In this example e1 would be an Integer and e2 remains String. I have been searching for a solution during several hours, and the best I have found is a [solution with reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589542/11458943)

However it cast to String, indepently if it contains other type of information, causing malfunctions in other parts of the code.

Comment: A `String` is only every a String. You can only cast it to `String`, `Object`, or one of the interfaces implemented by `String`. If you want to **convert** it to an Integer, you need to use a method or constructor, such as `new Integer(s)`.

Comment: That is not how generics work. Generics are *almost* ***solely*** a compile time type checking system (plus one little cast at runtime). And a `String` cannot be cast to an int, it must be *parsed*.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Don't use the `Integer` constructor, as it is deprecated in newer Java versions. Use `valueOf` instead.

Comment: I think it's an interesting idea actually, but what would you expect from this: "EUR 10 only"? You could have the string that it is, a number (10), 2 strings ("EUR", "only"), and an ISO currency code, if you have some [Enum of that kind](https://gist.github.com/Aquazus/1a26a55ba7c38ed0363e0068d389cf30) somewhere (EUR). So there is no auto-decoding possible.

Comment: @gurioso I work with Strings that represent one type of data per String. If that situation is given, the different “types” of String are previously separated

Comment: Still, Java isn't built that way. I'm not sure if any languages are out there who try to do this, but there are framweworks who can, I think of web-scraping stuff. But since you know your data you don't need to let the language guess, you can tell it what to do (convert). Ha, Javascript does soemthing like this, they call it type extortion or so, and it makes it very unreliable, so they invented stuff like TypeScript to prevent it from happening.

Comment: @gurioso Is it possible to use the id of the strings to compare its information according to the naturalOrder? I mean, would it work the same if it represented a String, Integer or Double?

Comment: My goal is to read a txt file (representing one type of data) which contains (per line) a list of this data and the range within I should compare every element of the list. All this as a string, and the data variate per file (read several files)

Comment: My problem isn’t about how to separate the values, it is how to parse the value respect to its information

Comment: Yeah that’s right, but the thing is that I don’t know the format. It changes, there are several files to read **each one with completely different data types** so I can’t create cases for them all, I need a default variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's some terminological friction between your notion of "generic" (the kind of information that e.g. the 2nd and 3rd characters of "€10.-" might represent) and [generic types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html), which is a Java technical term and concept.

There are some things below, that objects of class `String` are compatible with. Only `Comparable` is considered a generic type in the Java technical sense (here it has the type parameter `<String>`), all the rest is not.

```
public final class String implements java.io.Serializable, 
Comparable<String>, CharSequence, Constable, ConstantDesc
```

You don't need to cast a String to any of them. You can just do stuff like this:

```
String s = "10";
CharSequence c = s;
```

If you go the other way round and you have `CharSequence c` then you can find out if it is actually String, and if it is, then you can cast. Btw. also the ["reflection approach"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24589542/1428369) you referred to tests (`clazz.isAssignableFrom`) before it casts.

```
CharSequence c = new StringBuffer("Käse");
if(c instanceOf String) // it is not, it is instanceOf StringBuffer
{
   String anotherString = (String) c;
}
```

What you talked about isn't about casting but converting or evaluating. You can get an Integer from a String using Integer's conversion method `valueOf()`.

```
   Integer two = Integer.valueOf("2");
```

But it may fail, e.g. if you try this `Integer.valueOf("€10.-")` you'd get a `NumberFormatException`. You'd need to pick the numerical part only to make it work `Integer.valueOf("€10.-".substring(1, 3))`